# Steepest descent and finding optimal step size

Tags: python, algorithm, derivative, calculus

I'm trying to a Steepest descent for a function with 2 variables. It works fine with **known** step size which = 0.3. But I want to find a way to optimize step size and create a function to find a good step size. I found something called Armijo–Goldstein condition but I didn't understand it and the formula was kind of confusing for me. So I ask your help, if you have an idea how to balance this 'cause everything that connected to the step size at my code is wrong, I think. It have to calculate step size deepening on x and y we're on, I guess.

```
x, y = f.optimal_range()  ##getting random start
step = 0.3 ## <--- This number have to be random between 0 to 1. But my step size calculations are wrong so I can't do it.


while f.fprime_x(x) != 0:  ##loop to find 0 point for derivative of a function on x
    fx = -f.fprime_x(x)
    x = x + (step * fx)
    print(x)
    if not f.delta_check(step, x, y): <--- Here's the problem. By the defenition the step have to be smaller if it doesn't pass the check, but if I make it smaller - it enters the eternal loop around the mi
        step = step * 1.001


while f.fprime_y(y) != 0:  ##loop to find 0 point for derivative of a function on x
    fy = -f.fprime_y(y)
    y = y + (step * fy)
    print(x, y)
    if not f.delta_check(step, x, y):
        step = step * 1.001


print(f"\n\nMIN ({x}, {y})")
```

Here's the function of delta / step size checking:

```
def delta_check(delta, x, y):
    ux = -fprime_x(x)
    uy = -fprime_y(y)
    f_del_xy = func(x + (delta * ux), y + (delta * uy))
    return f_del_xy <= func(delta * ux, delta * uy) + delta
```

Comment: "So I ask your help, if you have an idea how to balance this 'cause everything that connected to the step size at my code is wrong, "  Isn't a specific question.  What part of you code isn't working?

Comment: Could you spot on what is not working? What would by the expected results, why the current result does not match. Also provides links to methodology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a notional Armijo–Goldstein implementation. Can't test it without a data+function example, though.

```
# both should be less than, but usually close to 1
c = 0.8  # how much imperfection in function improvement we'll settle up with
tau = 0.8  # how much the step will be decreased at each iteration

x = np.array(f.optimal_range())  # assume everything is a vector; x is an n-dimensional coordinate

# NOTE: the part below is repeated for every X update
step = 0.3  # alpha in Armijo–Goldstein terms    
gradient = np.array(f.fprime_x(x[0]), f.fprime_y(x[1]), ...)
# in the simplest case (SGD) p can point in the direction of gradient,
# but in general they don't have to be the same, e.g. because of added momentum
p = -gradient / ((gradient**2).sum() **0.5)
m = gradient.dot(p)  # "happy case" improvement per unit step
t = - c * m  # improvement we'll consider good enough
# func(*x) might be worth precomputing
while func(*x) - func(*(x + step*p)) < step *  t:  # good enough step size found
    step *= tau

# update X and repeat
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I didn't understand at all what what is c and t at the formula before! Thanks!